# Capturing Headers in a List Using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string I am trying to capture from (let's call it `output`):

```
ltm pool TEST_POOL { 
    Some strings
    above headers
    records { 
        baz:1 {
            ANY STRING
            HERE 
        } 
        foobar:23 { 
            ALSO ANY
            STRING HERE 
        }
    }
    members {
        qux:45 {
            ALSO ANY
            STRINGS HERE
        }
        bash:2 {
            AND ANY
            STRING HERE
        }
        topaz:789 {
            AND ANY
            STRING HERE
        }        
    }
    Some strings
    below headers
}
```

Consider each line of `output` to be separated by a typical line break.  For the sake of this question, let's refer to `records` and `members` as "titles" and `baz`, `foobar`, `qux`, `bash`, and `topaz` as "headers". I am trying to formulate a regex in Java that will capture all headers between the brackets of a given title in a find loop.  For example, given we want to find all headers of title `members` with this code:

```
        String regex = TODO; // members\\s\\{ contained in regex
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

The output should be ...

```
qux
bash
topaz
```

And should exclude `baz` and `foobar` because they are contained within the brackets of a different "title".  There can be any number of titles and any number of headers.  Some help in formulating a regex to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex using `\G` that asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match:

```
(?:\bmembers\s*\{|(?<!^)\G[^{]+\{[^}]+\})\s*?\n\s*([^:{}]+)(?=:\d)
```

OR:

```
(?:\brecords\s*\{|(?<!^)\G[^{]+\{[^}]+\})\s*?\n\s*([^:{}]+)(?=:\d)
```

This is assuming there are no nested and escaped `{` and `}`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR4uY4/2)

Comment: Hmmm but it seems if I change `member` to `records` it doesn't capture anything anymore.  Could this be changed to accommodate this?

Comment: Thank you.  If you don't think this question is a total crime would you mind nullifying the negative vote against it with an up vote?  I'll never understand people who down-vote with no comment.

Comment: Even I don't understand why it was downvoted, I have voted it up.

Comment: Really sorry to inconvenience you, but if I expanded my question a bit to include also not matching on headers that contain a given string within their brackets (the `ANY STRINGS HERE` part) could you modify you answer to account for that?  I'm having a hard time hacking it out myself, and I definitely don't want to unaccept your answer so I thought I'd ask you directly first here before editing the question or creating a new question.  Thanks!

Comment: I think that would change the originally stated question. Usually a negative lookahead takes care of that, like  `((?!dontMatchThis)[^:{}]+)`. If you cannot get it right please open a new question as it is awfully late here.

Comment: Ok thank you. I've posted my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338301/implementing-a-negative-lookahead-in-regex