# Implementing a Negative Lookahead in Regex to exclude a block of code if it contains a certain string

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

This is a follow up to an original question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320744/capturing-headers-in-a-list-using-regex), but I would appreciate help in expanding its capabilities a bit.  I have the following string I am trying to capture from (let's call it output):

```
ltm pool TEST_POOL { 
    Some strings
    above headers
    records { 
        baz:1 {
            ANY STRING
            HERE
            session-status enabled
        } 
        foobar:23 { 
            ALSO ANY
            STRING HERE
            session-status enabled
        }
    }
    members {
        qux:45 {
            ALSO ANY
            STRINGS HERE
            session-status enabled
        }
        bash:2 {
            AND ANY
            STRING HERE
            session-status user-disabled
        }
        topaz:789 {
            AND ANY
            STRING HERE
            session-status enabled
        }        
    }
    Some strings
    below headers
}
```

Consider each line of output to be separated by a typical line break. For the sake of this question, let's refer to `records` and `members` as "titles" and `baz`, `foobar`, `qux`, `bash`, and `topaz` as "headers". I am trying to formulate a regex in Java that will capture all headers between the brackets of a given title EXCEPT those that contain the string `session-status user-disabled` between their own header brackets as can be seen above. For example, given we want to find all headers of title `members` with this code:

```
String regex = "(?:\\bmembers\\s*\\{|(?<!^)\\G[^{]+\\{[^}]+\\})\\s*?\\n\\s*([^:{}]+)(?=:\\d)";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The output should be just ...

```
qux
topaz
```

Thus, it should exclude the `bash` header because it has `session-status user-disabled` in between its brackets. I'm having trouble implementing a negative lookahead in the regex I'm using to accomplish this. In addition, `baz` and `foobar` should also not match because they are contained within the brackets of a different "title" all together. There can be any number of titles and any number of headers. Some help in modifying my regex to include a negative lookahead to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you still want to use a regex rather than writing a real parser for this?

Comment: @Robert Eh, the thing is it's pretty unlikely I'll need to break this data apart in any other way in the near future.  Any particular tools you would recommend for parsing this if I decide to go that direction in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built off of your previous expression and added an alternation that will attempt to match any "header" using a non-capturing group if it contains the string `session-status user-disabled`. In doing so, those "headers" will be negated because they aren't captured. Only titles of "headers" that contain the string `session-status enabled` will be matched.

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/gH8zC5/1)

```
(?:\bmembers\s*\{|(?<!^)\G)\s*?\n\s*(?:(?:[^{]*\{[^}]*?session-status user-disabled[^}]*\})|([^:{}]+)(?=:\d)[^{]*\{[^}]*\})
```